# Finding an angle in a triangle formed by constructions with angle bisectors

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, angle

AD, BF and CE are the angle bisectors of the $\triangle{ABC}$. $\angle{BAC}=120°$. How to find $\angle{EDF}$?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K$ be placed on the line $AC$ such that $A$ placed between $F$ and $K$.

Thus, $$\measuredangle CAD=\measuredangle DAB=\measuredangle BAK=60^{\circ},$$
which says that $AB$ is a bisector of $\angle DAK$.

But also $CE$ is a bisector of $\angle ACB$ and $$CE\cap AB=\{E\},$$
which gives that $DE$ is a bisector of $\angle ADB$.

By the same way we can show that $DF$ is a bisector of $\angle ADC,$

which says $$\measuredangle EDF=\frac{180^{\circ}}{2}=90^{\circ}.$$

I used the following facts.

> Each point of an angle bisector is equidistant from the sides of the angle.

and

> If a point is placed inside the angle and equidistant from the sides of the angle then this point is placed on the bisector of the angle.

Let $d(A,l)$ be the distance between a point $A$ and a line $l$.

Since $CE$ is a bisector of $\angle ACB$, we obtain:
$$d(E,AC)=d(E,BC).$$
Since $AB$ is a bisector of $\angle DAK$, we obtain:
$$d(E,AK)=d(E,AD).$$
But lines $AC$ and $AK$ they are the same.

Also, lines $DB$ and $BC$ they are the same.

Thus, $$d(E,AD)=d(E,AK)=d(E,AC)=d(E,BC)=d(E,DB),$$
which says $$d(E,AD)=d(E,DB)$$ and from here the ray $DE$ is a bisector of $\angle ADB$.

Comment: How did you conclude that DE is a bisector of ∠ADB?

Comment: I checked on GeoGebra with different combinations of $angle{C}$ and $angle{B}$ and the $angle{EDF}$ indeed comes out to be $90°$.

Comment: I tried editing my comment above but could not because of 5 minutes limit. Like I was saying, I checked on GeoGebra with different combinations of $\angle{C}$ and $\angle{B}$ and the $\angle{EDF}$ indeed comes out to be 90°. However, this proof is way too difficult for me. Could you please explain which theorems/results you have used to arrive at the conclusion that DE bisects ∠ADB. I'm sorry you've to deal with my ignorance.

Comment: @Trdp I added something. See now.

Comment: This clears it up. You are very kind, thank you.